# Cannot access AWS instance with Elastic IP in my browser

Tags: amazon-web-services, elastic-ip

I have followed what the guideline(https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonVPC/latest/UserGuide/VPC_Internet_Gateway.html) has told me to do, and my instance have an Elastic IP. However, when I paste the Elastic IP into my browsers(Google Chrome/ Microsoft Edge) none of them worked. [Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IVEdG.png) is a screenshot of the Security groups.

Any help is appreciated!

update 1: Sorry I am new to stackoverflow and forgot to post the screenshot last time. Now you can view the picture.

update 2: I think I've connected my instance with the Elastic IP. See [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Yg1J.png)

update 3: Thanks everyone who offered help. I think I've made it. It is actually something about the firewall :-)

Comment: Check if you have linked your instance with your elastic ip

Comment: I think you forgot to attach your screenshot :)

Comment: You should attach the screenshot that shows the problem you are facing.

Comment: @thebrownkid I think I've done that, please check update 2.

Comment: @JorgRoper Just added. Sorry about that :-)

Comment: @ArashKazemi Just added lol. Sorry I am new to stackoverflow.